# How to add index label in google chart stack bar

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, column-chart

I have a stack bar using google chart

But, I don't understand how to put the labels inside

This is what i want to achieve. please see image attached
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyaGn.png)

This is my code

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
          </script>
          <script type = "text/javascript">
             google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});     
          </script>


          <div id = "container" style = "width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
          </div>
          <script language = "JavaScript">
             function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
             'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
            ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
            ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
            ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
          ]);

                var options = {
                                title: "h",
                                width: 600,

                                legend: { position: "none" },
                                isStacked:true
                            };

                var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('container'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
                function selectHandler(e) {
                      var selection = chart.getSelection();
                      if (selection.length == true && selection[0].row != null) {
                        console.log(selection[0])
                           //alert('You selected ' +data.getValue(selection[0].row, selection[0].column));
                           //window.open(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0));
                            window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q='+data.getValue(selection[0].row, selection[0].column));
                       } 
                    }
             }
             google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          </script>
```

Comment: you will need to add an annotation column after each series column, see [labeling columns](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#labeling-columns)...

Comment: that was done in a single column. how to do it in stacked bar?

Comment: add an annotation column after every series column...